# Call UI input via string: R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Thanks in advance.

Wondering if there is a way to call a ui element via string in the server.r file.

Example:
instead of ...

```
ui.Color <- input$color
```

do something like ...

```
ui.Color <- input[,"color"]
```

...kind of like you could do with a data frame. Issue is class(input) yields reactiveValues so I'm not quite sure how to subset it to get a particular value.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 9):

Got it!

```
input[["color"]]
```

Hope this helps others with the same question!

Comment: Does this still work?  I've noticed some odd behavior with recent updates in the shiny package.